# What is a predicate transformer?

Tags: semantics, hoare-logic, denotational-semantics

I'm reading *[Programming - The derivation of algorithms](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb140ksgwa8y3dd/Programming%20-%20The%20derivation%20of%20algorithms.pdf?dl=0)*, and I want to understand the purpose of a **predicate transformer**. This is the excerpt (p. 14-15):

> A more precise way in which constructs may be introduced is as follows. For each construct $S$ one defines a **predicate transformer**, denoted $wp.S$, which is a function from predicates to predicates. For construct $S$ and predicate $Q$, $wp.S.Q$ is interpreted as the weakest predicate $P$ for which $\{P\}\,S\,\{Q\}$ holds. It is called the **weakest precondition** of $S$ with respect to $Q$. The relation between the expressions $\{P\}\,S\,\{Q\}$ and $wp.S.Q$ is given by
>
> $$ \{P\}\,S\,\{Q\}$ \text{ is equivalent to } [P \implies wp.S.Q]$$

Explain me the concept predicate transformer. What is its purpose?

Answer (score 9):

The predicate transformer is just a formalization of the idea that you can produce a precondition given a program and its postcondition.

For example, given a program `sqrt` with the postcondition that `sqrt(x) = y` and `y*y = x`, what are some valid preconditions?

- x > 10
- x > 20
- x > 1

Some invalid preconditions would be

- x < 0
- x > -10

One predicate `P1` is weaker than another predicate `P2` if `P2 => P1`, but it is not true that `P1 => P2`. For example, `x > 1` is weaker than `x > 10` because `x > 10` implies `x > 1` as well, but `x > 1` does *not* imply `x > 10`; `x == 3` would be a counterexample.

Given all possible preconditions for our square-root program, one must be the weakest of them all; we denote that with the function `wp.S.Q` (which you could also write in the more familiar notation `wp(S, Q)`). In this case, `wp.S.Q = {x >=0 }`. You can prove that if `x` satisfies any precondition `P`, then it must satisfy `x >= 0`, and that if it does not satisfy `x >= 0`, it cannot satisfy any other precondition `P`.

The idea of a weakest precondition is useful because it allows a program to work with as many values as possible. Using a precondition of `x >= 20` isn't useful because it doesn't allow us to compute the square root of 4.

Note that just because `wp.S.Q` is *defined*, that doesn't mean we have to provide an algorithm to actually compute its value. Doing so would provide a constructive proof of its existence, but non-constructive proofs could be found as well.